# Django: how to order_by on a related field of a related field

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by, annotate

I'm using annotate to add a property to an object which I can then use for order_by. However, I want to annotate on a field of a relation on a relation. I know I should be able to get to the field somehow using double-underscore notation, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Here are the models:

```
class Group(Taggable, Uploadable):
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    description     = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True,
                        blank=True, db_index=True)
    private         = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    members         = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True,
                        related_name='members', through='GroupToUser')
    pending_members = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True,
                        related_name='pending_members')
    admin           = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    timestamp       = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author          = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='author')

class Discussion(Taggable, Uploadable):
    author      = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=250, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=5000, null=True,
                    blank=True, db_index=True)
    group       = models.ForeignKey(Group, null=True)
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class DiscussionResponse(Uploadable):
    author     = models.ForeignKey(User)
    discussion = models.ForeignKey(Discussion)
    message    = models.TextField(max_length=5000)
    timestamp  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

So, a Discussion can optionally be associated with a Group, and DiscussionResponses are associated with a discussion. What I would like to do is find the most recent DiscussionResponse on any discussions connected to a Group, if it exists, and sort by that.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
Group.objects.filter(some_filtering).distinct().annotate(
    last_response=Max('some__reverse__relationship__timestamp').order_by(
        '-last_response')
```

I just can't seem to figure out the right way to get to the timestamp on a DiscussionResponse in this case.

**UPDATE:**
You can indeed order by an annotated value. Here is an example with an `order_by` on the timestamp of a related discussion:

```
>>> groups = Group.objects.all().annotate(
        last_response=Max('discussion__timestamp')).order_by('-last_response')
>>> for group in groups:
...     print(group.id, group.last_response)
...     
... 
(2L, datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 8, 15, 32, 31))
(1L, None)
(3L, None)
(4L, None)
(6L, None)
(7L, None)
(8L, None)
(9L, None)
```

In this case, only group #2 has related discussions so it was moved to the top; the rest retain the natural order. What I'd really like to do, though, is move groups that have recent **responses** to discussions moved to the top of the list. That's why I thought `'discussion__discussionresponse__timestamp'` would work, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I've tried the following, none of which worked: `discussion__discussionresponse__timestamp`, `discussion_set__discussionresponse__timestamp`, and `discussion set__discussionresponse__timestamp`

Comment: I don't understand what you try to accomplish. For example, you declare `last_response=Max(...)` that will give you a timestamp, and then you order_by this value, you have to order by column, not a value, am I right? What you want is order by timestamp colum??

Comment: You can `order_by` on an annotated value; I've used the trick before. The problem is, I can't seem to get to the timestamp of the DiscussionResponses related to the Discussions related to a Group.

Comment: You're field lookup string would be `discussion__discussionresponse_timestamp`, notice the **single** underscore before the timestamp. Are you doing that? In your update you show two underscores before timestamp.

Comment: @PauloBu That single underscore doesn't work, at least not in Django 1.4: `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'discussionresponse_timestamp' into field. Choices are: author, description, discussionresponse, file_url, group, id,
 image_height, image_url, image_width, mimetype, tags, timestamp, title`

Comment: Well, it might not work, but fields lookup use double underscore for chaining tables and single underscore for accessing fields. Is not working for some other reason. What's odd is that chaining two tables work and not chaining 3.

Comment: Your edit means that `discussionresponse` is available from `discussion`. It is weird to me that `discussionresponse_timestamp` doesn't work. Let me do some research

Comment: Ok, double underscores is the way to go! Sorry, have you tried doing it without the the annotate? Just to see what happens?

Comment: @PauloBu I haven't; the annotate trick works because we want the most recent response time, and to order the Groups with the newest responses first. I.e., those groups are "highlighted" because they have more recent activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, apparently it **is** just `'discussion__discussionresponse__timestamp'`. I tried it in the Django shell and it didn't work after saving a new DiscussionResponse, but it worked several minutes later when I tried it again:

```
>>> groups = Group.objects.all().annotate(last_response=Max(
        'discussion__discussionresponse__timestamp')).order_by('-last_response')
>>> for group in groups:
...     print(group.id, group.last_response)
...     
... 
(2L, datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 14, 56, 22))
(1L, None)
(3L, None)
(4L, None)
(6L, None)
(7L, None)
(8L, None)
(9L, None)
>>>
```

If anyone knows why it didn't work right after saving a new object to the database, but did work later, that would probably be useful information.

Here's another run at the query with discussions/responses added to another group just for added verification:

```
>>> groups = Group.objects.all().annotate(last_response=Max('discussion__discussionresponse__timestamp')).order_by('-last_response')
>>> for group in groups:
...     print(group.id, group.last_response)
...     
... 
(4L, datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 15, 25, 40))
(2L, datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 16, 15, 16, 46))
(1L, None)
(3L, None)
(6L, None)
(7L, None)
(8L, None)
(9L, None)
>>>
```