# Order queryset by related M2M fields Django

Tags: django

I'm trying to order a QuerySet by the field of three related intermediary models. Let me simplify my current scenario, let's assume I have these models.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    about_me = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class School(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=_(u'Name'))
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, verbose_name=_(u'Email'))
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True,
                         verbose_name=_(u'Phone'))

    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                    verbose_name=_(u'Administrators'),
                                    through='SchoolAdmins',
                                    related_name='school_administered')


    assistants = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                        verbose_name=_(u'Assistants'),
                                        through='SchoolAssistants',
                                        related_name='school_assisted')


    instructors = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                         verbose_name=_(u'Instructors'),
                                         through='SchoolInstructors',
                                         related_name='school_instructed')


class SchoolAdmins(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_(u'Staff ordering number'))



class SchoolAssistants(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_(u'Staff ordering number'))


class SchoolInstructors(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name=_(u'Staff ordering number'))
```

Notice the order field in the intermediary models SchoolAdmins, SchoolInstructors and SchoolAssistants, it is used to denote the view ordering level when rendering users in a template, thus, the order specied is important (although it can be None, zero or even duplicated)

That said, I need to return a QuerySet that is ordered by the order field of the intermediary models.

Getting the users is easy:

```
        qs = User.objects.filter(Q(schoolassistants__school__id=school_id) |
                             Q(schooladmins__school__id=school_id) |
                             Q(schoolinstructors__school__id=school_id))
```

But I'm not sure how to order queryset based on the order field...is this even possible? I'd like to avoid having to do this in Python if possible...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594862/django-how-to-order-by-on-a-related-field-of-a-related-field and see if it helps you in any way

Comment: @pawel.ad related but I have a slight different situation, where the field is present in all 3 intermediary models...not just one

Comment: Ah, my bad. In that case, if all of `SchoolAdmins`, `SchoolAssistants`, `SchoolInstructors` have the same structure, why not create a `SchoolStaff` model that replaces all of them and has an additional `role` field with `choices=['Admin', 'Assistant', 'Instructor']`? It would simplify the data structure greatly and I don't see an obvious downside, as you could reimplement `School.admins` with custom manager methods.
If that's a no go then I don't think you'll be able to do it without either Python ordering or raw SQL.

Comment: @pawel.ad As commented, this is a simplified version of my real models, I cannot simply throw away SchoolAdmins, SchoolAssistants and SchoolInstructors models because they are used to do more stuff than simply indicate staff role. I've managed to do this with Python, but was wondering if there is a more SQLish way to do it..

Comment: In that case I have one last idea - I'd use https://github.com/django-polymorphic/django-polymorphic and make then all inherit after `SchoolStaff` which should make the above query set achievable. I used it couple of times and always liked it a lot. Let me know if that works for you and if you need a any help setting it up.

Comment: @pawel.ad Hmmm worth a try...I'll let you know how it goes, thanks for sharing pawel!